# How to search if there are unnecessary character between two set of strings using regex?

Tags: regex

MUST RETURN **TRUE**:

```
kWordSyntaxSearch = "something~~abc#include";
kWordSyntaxSearch = "something~~a bc#include";
kWordSyntaxSearch = "something~~ abc#include";
kWordSyntaxSearch = "something~~abc #include";
```

MUST RETURN **FALSE**:

```
kWordSyntaxSearch = "something~~#include<";
```

WHAT I'VE DONE SO FAR

```
    //JUST SEARCHING FOR THE EXISTENCE OF #include
if(kwordSyntaxSearch_tilde.indexOf("#include")!= -1  &&  !/~~\s*#include\s*/.test(kwordSyntaxSearch_tilde) )
```

I want to pass the condition above if it found "#include" in kwordSyntaxSearch and then **check if there are unnecessary characters in between ~~ and #include.**

(Just details)
~~ was put on the kWordSyntaxSearch to put a mark that the syntax before that is correct, and i just wanted to trigger an error when this happened:

```
#include<iostream.h>usdfsd
#include<conio.h>
```

Comment: It looks like you're trying to use regex to parse - it's probably better to use an actual parser if that's your overall goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a negative look behind:

```
kwordSyntaxSearch.*(?<!~~)#include.*
```

This doesn't require the `~~` to exist.

If it's *required* that `~~` exist:

```
kwordSyntaxSearch.*~~[^~]+#include.*
```

Comment: this gives me a syntax error in dw: /*~~[^~]+#include.*/.test(kwordSyntaxSearch_tilde). Isn't its how i use your answer?

Comment: You seem to be missing a dot from your comment at the start: between the leading slash and the star

Comment: thanks, i modified it to /~~\s*\S+\s*#include/.test(kwordSyntaxSearch_tilde) and now works just fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might perhaps use this regex?

```
~~(?=.+#include)
```

See how it's working [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/zN0qN3).

Since matches return TRUE and non-matches return FALSE, that should do it I think.

Answer (score 0):

The following regex should extract the unnecessary characters in between ~~ and #include

```
(?<=~~).+(?=#include)
```

Then you can check the resulting String for emptiness, if it is, then TRUE.

NB:If you tag the language of preference, I may give you a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

Try this regex pattern:

```
kWordSyntaxSearch = ".*~~.{1,}#include.*
```

Comment: Note that `{1,}` is `+`.